# Phpunit testing form in Symfony 6

Tags: symfony, datetime, phpunit

I am trying to write a test for a form which contains Datime object. Other fields are working out, but the Datetime comes allways just as expected in the results and the test is failing because of that. Does somebody have an idea why is it so?

Here is my code

```
public function testSubmitValidData(): void
{
    $date = new \DateTime('2023-06-05 00:00:00');
    $formData = [
        'name' => 'test name',
        'description' => 'test description',
        'price'=>100,
        'purchased_at' => $date
    ];

    $model = new Product();
    $form = $this->factory->create(ProductType::class, $model);

    $expected = new Product();

    $expected->setPurchasedAt($date);
    $expected->setName('test name');
    $expected->setDescription('test description');
    $expected->setPrice(10000);

 
    $form->submit($formData);

    // This works
    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

    
    // this is not working because of Datetime object
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $model);
}
```

Here is the result of testing:

```
1) App\Tests\Form\Type\TestedTypeTest::testSubmitValidData
Failed asserting that two objects are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
     'name' => 'test name'
     'description' => 'test description'
     'price' => 10000
-    'purchased_at' => DateTime Object (...)
     'user' => null
     'users' => Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object (...)
 )
```

Here is date entry in ProductType

```
->add('purchased_at', DateTimeType::class, array(
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'min date',
                    'required' => false,
                    'id' => 'purchased_at')))
```

Comment: I believe you end up with a different instance after being converted to string value for the form and then back to `DateTime`, so you would have to check individual fields and manually compare `DateTime` values. But, I also noticed you are using a different price value, `'price'=>100,` vs `$expected->setPrice(10000);`

Comment: How do I manualy compare fields? Could you post a link to the documentation or a example?

Price is ok. In form is this: ->add('price', MoneyType::class, ['divisor' => 100])

Answer (score 0):

Please review options in your date time type as I do not see your `date_widget` and other format options https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#date-widget, you probably want to `$formData` not DateTime Object but some other stuff like string with date for example, that option decide how to treat input

Please debug what you gets as argument in `setPurchasedAt` as it should be called cause of [property access component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access.html) is used by default by forms.

Please review if correct property access is used.